# Need to select em in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, selenium-ide, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium IDE in Chrome.

I have trouble as it's `Ext JS`, so certain class names are generated. I also might be having trouble due to the class name **"x-list-body"**?

I want to click on **"This person here yes"**, like this:

```
Click: //div[@class='x-list']//em[.='This person here yes']
```

Here is the HTML from the webpage, excuse the mess:

```
<div class="x-list-body">
<div id="ext-gen159" class="x-list-body-inner">
<dl>
<dt style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
<em unselectable="on" "="">Woot Moot Boot</em>
</dt>
<div class="x-clear">
</div>
</dl>
<dl>
<dt style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
<em unselectable="on" "="">This is sparta</em>
</dt>
<div class="x-clear"></div></dl>
<dl>
<dt style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
<em unselectable="on" "="">Henry Print</em>
</dt>
<div class="x-clear"></div>
</dl>
<dl>
<dt style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
<em unselectable="on" "="">Minsy Blowman</em>
</dt>
<div class="x-clear"></div>
</dl>
<dl class="">
<dt style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
<em unselectable="on" "="">This person here yes</em>
</dt>
<div class="x-clear"></div>
</dl>
<dl class="">
<dt style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
<em unselectable="on" "="">Another cool person</em>
</dt>
<div class="x-clear"></div>
</dl>
</div>
</div>
```

Please do not give me `JavaScript` code etc..., I am using the `FireFox` addon IDE.

Thank you!

Comment: have u tried using contains in the css selector

Comment: @sai No, how would I do that sorry?

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em[contains(text(),'This person here yes')]")).click();
```

Comment: How do I use that? This is what my IDE looks like, where do I put it? https://s32.postimg.org/ln088zfmd/image.jpg     Looks like JS to me...

Comment: I did click:          //em[contains(text(),'steve Steve deSilva Job London')]   but sadly it just gets highlighted in red, same issue as before sorry.

Comment: what is happening if you are clicking on that element manually.

Comment: When I use the website normally? I click it and it is highlighted, next I click an arrow. https://s31.postimg.org/qm15vv6pn/image.jpg

Comment: similarly we have done click and it is getting highlighted.Then try to click on arrow webelement.

Comment: or try using clickandwait instead of click

Comment: Your code does not make it highlight sorry. Clicking on the arrow works though as I tested that line of code. The problem is highlighting, it's an error it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry it still didn't work when I tried clickAndWait, it fails like before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, class name is a problem. If you don't want an exact match, then change selector to match partial class name:

```
//div[contains(@class,'x-list')]//em[.='This person here yes']
```

Also since you are selecting a very particular text, you may not even need that `div` selector, unless another `em` on the page has exactly the same text. I.e. you may be able to use:

```
//em[.='This person here yes']
```